# How to use Jenkins parameter in parametrized job in configuration matrix value

Tags: jenkins

So, I created a parametrized job (choices) and I want to use that variable that the user will choose when building the job and set it in value in configuration matrix like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4pfE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sEaO.png)

Comment: Is [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#matrix-cell-directives) what you want?

Comment: Can you see pictures provided please?

Comment: I have a little confused about why you want to assign the user choice option to be a Configuration Matrix value. The Configuration Matrix is used to specify what steps to duplicate, and create a multiple-axis graph of the type of builds to create. Can you give some scenarios?

Comment: Ok from the other side, how can I put Values of configuration matrix in multiple choice to let the user choose before build, that's what I want.

Comment: I need to put values in user-defined-axis and let the user chooses what to build, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found the solution by only downloading the plugin **Dynamic Axis** and now I can use the variable of parameterized job inside configuration matrix.